Make Sticky Ads Using WordPress Column
i have a WordPress block column on my homepage and tried to put ads sticky on the right column, i think it can achieved just simply with this code, but it doesn't work.
i believed something prevent the sticky not work because of the WordPress block column which i don't know how to set the position is.
<style>

.iklansticky {
 position: -webkit-sticky;
 position: sticky;
 top: 0;
}

</style>

<p style="margin:auto 0;text-align:center;font-size:12px;">Iklan</p>
<script async src="https://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js?client=ca-pub-xxxxxxx"
     crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<!-- Display Ad -->
<ins class="adsbygoogle iklansticky"
     style="display:block"
     data-ad-client="ca-pub-xxxxxxx"
     data-ad-slot="xxxxxxx"
     data-ad-format="auto"
     data-full-width-responsive="true"></ins>
<script>
     (adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
</script>
<p style="margin:auto 0;text-align:center;font-size:12px;">Ads By Google!</p>

